# Problem with GetFeatureInfo on WMS

Tags: geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

I'm trying to retrieve the informations about points around the mouse click. However if the click is not on the inside the symbol but just outside, the WMS returns an empty response.

To simplify the question here are two screenshots:

[image: Here the response of the server contains the information]

Here the response of the server contains the information

[image: Here the response of the server contains nothing]

Here the response of the server contains nothing because the point is in the middle.

I would like to know if there is a way to ask the GeoServer WMS to return the features with more tolerance (given that the parameter feature_count is already set at 50)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably hit a side effect of heavy work what was done with GeoServer GetFeatureInfo to return info from what is exactly rendered on the map. With the style used in your map there is nothing rendered between the markers.

You can have a try by adding a buffer vender parameter into your GetFeatureInfo request. The default value is 3, try to add &buffer=10 into your request http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html