# Find the nearest point to take through GeoServer using GetFeatureInfo

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms, getfeatureinfo

We developed own street view functions with our 360 degree photos. We have lots of points to show photos take places on map. If click on these points, you can see photos as 360 degree like Google Street View. But if not click on these points, you can not see anything. Because, not get any data from GeoServer with GetFeatureInfo query.

I want to get data when clicked between two points, so I want to get nearest 360 degree point from WMS.

How can I do that?

[image: map]

GetFeatureInfo Query sample:

```
http://localhost:54761/handlers/WMSService.ashx?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=TEST%3AmaxCountyView%2CTEST%3AmaxStateView%2CTEST%3AmaxDistrictView%2CTEST%3AmaxRoadView%2CTEST%3AmaxStructureView%2CTEST%3AmaxNumberView%2CTEST%3ASTREET_SHP2_STREET_POINT_Points&STYLES=&LAYERS=TEST%3AmaxCountyView%2CTEST%3AmaxStateView%2CTEST%3AmaxDistrictView%2CTEST%3AmaxRoadView%2CTEST%3AmaxStructureView%2CTEST%3AmaxNumberView%2CTEST%3ASTREET_SHP2_STREET_POINT_Points&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&feature_count=10&X=50&Y=50&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=3712592.9784559594%2C4190009.7198761674%2C3712596.743835624%2C4190013.485255832
```

Comment: I changed WFS to WMS in your question because GetFeatureInfo is an operation of a WMS, just like you have in your query sample.

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to GeoServer software The URL you have with .ashx suggests some .NET architecture, is it a proxy?

Comment: Yes, we use .ashx proxy, build with .net.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with GetFeatureInfo on WMS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153195/problem-with-getfeatureinfo-on-wms)

Comment: Maybe, it was about buffer, we already think about it, but if we use buffer and returns a lot of points, we don't know which one is the nearest point?

Comment: What if you have a layer with all the photo locations, just query it and never display it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80026/discussion-between-omur-bilgili-and-nmtoken).